# JPA (PlayFramework): Saving a Map<ClassA,ClassB> in the Database

Tags: database, jpa, dictionary, playframework, persistence

In my class *Organisation* I have an attribute which is a Map and I want to save it in the database.
I've tried a lot with @ManyToMany-Annotation and also with @ElementCollection but it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
@Entity
public class Organisation extends Model {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private Map<ClassA, ClassB> map;

  public Organisation(ClassA firstEntry){
    this.map = new HashMap<ClassA,ClassB>();
    ClassB value = new ClassB();
    value.save();
    map.put(firstEntry, value);
  }

  public Map<ClassA,ClassB> getMap(){
     return map;
  }

  public void setMap(Map<ClassA,ClassB> map){
    this.map = map;
  }
}
```

An the two other classes:

```
@Entity
public class ClassA extends Model{

  @Id
  private Long id;
  ...

  public ClassA(){
  ...
  }

  public Long getId(){
    return id;
  }
  ...
}


@Entity
public class ClassB extends Model{

  @Id
  private Long id;
  ...

  public ClassB(){
  ...
  }

  public Long getId(){
    return id;
  }
  ...
}
```

I can create all the objects and they all are in the database. But if I try to get them out, the map is allway null. (and I can't find a table which connects *Organisation*, *ClassA* an *ClassB*